# Set Input to read Only

Tags: jquery

I have this input which I need to set to `readonly` using jquery. Below is what I've done so far, but the code is not working. What is my mistake here?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" data-field-id="field26" name="field26[]" data-min-char="" data-max-char="" data-val-type="url" data-regexp="" data-is-required="false" data-allow-spaces="" class="validation-lenient" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" tooltip="" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-input-mask="" data-mask-placeholder="">
```

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    input('[data-field-id="field26"]').setAttribute("readonly", true);
    $('[data-field-id="field26"]').setAttribute("readonly", true);
});
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` for this

Comment: use `document.querySelector` https://jsfiddle.net/yv1roo2y/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-field-id="field26"]').attr("readonly", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#fieldName").prop("readonly", true);
```

or 
add atributed
disabled="disabled"

Comment: Disabled and readonly are not the same thing (disabled won't POST with the form for a start).